# systemd: forking process immediately calls execStop

Tags: linux, systemd, daemon

I've set this up as a barebones thing we'd like to get running on a machine:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/myscript/daemonWrapper start
# ExecStop=/opt/myscript/daemonWrapper stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My problem is that, so long as I keep ExecStop commented out, it runs totally fine. If I uncomment it and start the daemon, the service immediately calls ExecStop and stops running. It'd be nice to have an ExecStop, as the tool we're running does accommodate a stop command to cleanly exit. Not essential in our case, but I'd like to keep things clean, you know?

I think this is correctly set as a forking process as it's basically a wrapper script that sets some necessary environment variables before launching a script that runs in the background. I do notice most people use different scripts to start/stop daemons, so I wonder if there's something weird that might be popping up in this case from my doing that. I've tested that 'daemonWrapper' script (fake name, obviously) directly and it does everything it should for start/status/stop.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your reason for using `Type=forking`? This type is mainly provided for legacy daemons that are implemented as binary programs that do a double `fork` and also call `setsid` to disassociate themselves from the controlling terminal. I suspect the problem is caused by systemd losing track of the process id of the main process of the daemon, possibly because the program is backgrounded too many times. I note that you are not specifying the `PIDFile=` option, which is recommended when `Type=forking` is used. Does the program use a pid file for the `stop` command?

Comment: - It's a wrapper script which launches another script, so from the documentation it sounded like that was called for -- the command the service executes exits immediately. Sounds like I'm incorrect in thinking of that as a forking process?

- I didn't know the PIDFile was so crucial to this -- I just pared the init file down to the most basic version I thought I needed. Adding it in makes it start (and stay up) and stop as I'd expect! Thanks!

- But I do get this warning now:
myDaemon.service: Supervising process 12345 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.

Comment: To me this sounds like there is too much forking going on. Try starting the actual service with `exec`, this may fix the "not our child" message.

Comment: That gets rid of the not-our-child error, and does launch the daemon properly, but some how there's no PID file any more, so 'stop' doesn't do anything any more.

Comment: That's strange, adding the `exec` shouldn't change the logic in any way, it just eliminates the creation of a new process. It's hard for me to tell without more details.